# How to get the Text from TextBlock inside a DataTemplate in code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, accordion

I have an Accordion Control where I bind values and display them in a DataTemplate.
This is what I have in my user control :

```
<layoutToolkit:Accordion x:Name="MyAccordion">
<layoutToolkit:Accordion.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate >
        <TextBlock x:Name="Header" Text="{Binding Header}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</layoutToolkit:Accordion.ItemTemplate>
<layoutToolkit:Accordion.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock x:Name="Content" Text="{Binding Content}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="MyMethod" Content="Method" Click="MyMethod"/>
            </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</layoutToolkit:Accordion.ContentTemplate>
```

My binding is working, now i want to be able to use the Text from the textblock to apply in a method in code behind, but I want the value to be different depending on which Accordion is open.
Is it possible to achieve that ?

This is how my code-behind is :

```
        public MyUserCOntrol()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MyAccordion.SelectionMode = AccordionSelectionMode.ZeroOrOne;

        //method to fill the accordion
        this.MyAccordion.ItemsSource = MainWindow._RE.ListActionsParType;
    }

    public void MyMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string TxtBlockContent = ....;
        // so i can use this value in other operations
    }
```

I want to create a method (here it's myMethode) that I will apply on a button click and that use this value depending on which accordion is open

Comment: That's the wrong way to go about it. Where are you getting this `Header` property from? Whatever's in `MainWindow._RE.ListActionsParType`, make it implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and set its `Header` property in codebehind. That'll update the text in the Accordion item.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thank you for your answer. I manage to display all the informations using INotifyPropertyChanged. What I want is to be able to use the Text from the textblock as a string so I can use it in a method and I want that this value changes depending on which accordion is expanded

Comment: That's the wrong way to go about it. The text in the textblock is coming FROM the Header property. Change the Header property, the text will change.

Comment: @EdPlunkett thank, I managed to do what I wanted thanks to Divakar's answer. thank you for your time and sorry if I wasn't clear at first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get the text of the TextBlock you displayed in the DataTemplate, then you can achieve it by using the below way,

//In the textblock you used in XAML

```
<TextBlock Loaded="Txt_Loaded">
```

//In code-behind

```
private void Txt_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var myText = (sender as TextBlock).Text;
}
```

The above event will be fired whenever the TextBlock is loaded into view. So, you can get the text in the TextBlock as like in the above code.

Comment: thank you, that's what i was looking for. Sorry if I wasn't clear at first !

Comment: Welcome. Please upvote the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: I can't yet, I don't have enough reputation. Will do as soon as I have enough

Comment: No problem. It's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Use "BindingContextChanged" event to take sender(actual view, TextBlock).